# Accessing static variable only once for all the extending classes

Tags: java

My requirement is, I have an auth class that provides authentication token(which is a `String`) and that token can be used in all the other classes. I wrote a small piece of code but unfortunately all the other classes were generating the authentication token individually. So there were one auth token per class. But I quickly did some changes as below. Pls see if this is a right approach or is there a better way to do it?

```
public class AuthProvider {
    public static String authKey;
    public static String provideAuth() {
        AuthProvider pro = new AuthProvider();
        String key = pro.generateAuthKey();
        authKey = key;
        return key;
    }
    private String generateAuthKey() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int n = rand.nextInt(5000) + 1;
        return String.valueOf(n);
    }
}
```

The one above is my Auth provider class and it provides the auth token to all other classes

Now my child class called "FirstClass" that needs the auth token to perform other operations is as follows

```
public class FirstClass extends AuthProvider {

    public String getValueFromFirstClass() {
        AuthProvider.provideAuth();
        String s = AuthProvider.authKey;
        return "FirstClassAuth: " + s;
    }
}
```

My second child class called `SecondClass` which is going to be the main class because the `main` method calls the method in this class which is responsible for getting a certain value from the `FirstClass` too.

```
public class SecondClass extends AuthProvider {

    public String getValueFromSecondClass() {
        FirstClass firstClass = new FirstClass();
        String firstClassString = firstClass.getValueFromFirstClass();
        String s = AuthProvider.authKey;
        return "SecondClass Auth: " + s + " -------- " + firstClassString;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SecondClass class2 = new SecondClass();
        System.out.println(class2.getValueFromSecondClass());
    }
}
```

So my requirement is.. I don't need two different "AuthTokens" per child classes. I can work with one auth token in both `FirstClass` and `SecondClass`. So what I did is right? or is there a better approach?

Comment: I think you're looking for [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my approach, using a global constant with a `static` initialization block:

```
public class AuthProvider {
    public static final String AUTH_KEY;

    static {
        AUTH_KEY = String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(5000) + 1);
    }
}
```

Then, in any other class you can just use `AuthProvider.AUTH_KEY` to retrieve the value.

Comment: Ok. It's similar to what I did except that this one does not require a separate method for the random number generation (Which is my actual auth key generation method but just masked it for description purpose). And do you know if I have to extend this `AuthProvider` class in all my other classes that needs auth?

Comment: My approach has the additional benefit of the auth key being immutable because of the `final` declaration.

Comment: Ok. And do you know if I have to extend this AuthProvider class in all my other classes that needs auth?

Comment: Don't know what other functionality you're adding to `AuthProvider`. If you just need access to the key, no need to extend.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Do you know if there is a name for this concept or it's just plain java?

Comment: Plain Java. Global constant with static initialization block.

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly suggest that you use Singleton and Dependency Injection here:

```
public class AuthProvider {
    private static final AuthProvider _instance = new AuthProvider();
    private final String authKey;

    public AuthProvider() {
        authKey = String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(5000) + 1);
    }

    public static AuthProvider getInstance() {
        return _instance;
    }

    public String getAuthKey() {
        return authKey;
    }
}

public class FirstClass {
    private AuthProvider authProvider;

    public FirstClass(AuthProvider authProvider) {
        this.authProvider = authProvider;
    }

    public String getValueFromFirstClass() {
        String s = authProvider.getAuthKey();
        return "FirstClassAuth: " + s;
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

`SecondClass`, in this case, would look like:

```
public class SecondClass {
    private AuthProvider authProvider;

    public SecondClass(AuthProvider authProvider) {
        this.authProvider = authProvider;
    }

    public String getValueFromSecondClass() {
        FirstClass firstClass = new FirstClass(authProvider);
        String firstClassString = firstClass.getValueFromFirstClass();
        String s = authProvider.getAuthKey();
        return "SecondClass Auth: " + s + " -------- " + firstClassString;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SecondClass class2 = new SecondClass(AuthProvider.getInstance());
        System.out.println(class2.getValueFromSecondClass());
    }
}
```

Again, this is not the best solution. Usually we split the main method into a separate class called `Application.java` which only has `main` method.

**Edit 2:**

The reason why we avoid using `extends` is because that keyword is associated with *is a* paradigm. In your case it looks like you want to use the `AuthProvider` and express *dependency* - which in English would sound like '`FirstClass` and `SecondClass` cannot do their job without `AuthProvider`'.

That is done by constructor DI (Dependency Injection) where those two classes cannot be used (instantiated) without providing an instance of `AuthProvider`.

If you are not building an Web App, you don't even need to have `AuthProvider` as a Singleton:

```
public class AuthProvider {
    private final String authKey;

    public AuthProvider() {
        authKey = String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(5000) + 1);
    }

    public String getAuthKey() {
        return authKey;
    }
}
```

You would then change the `main` method to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SecondClass class2 = new SecondClass(new AuthProvider());
    System.out.println(class2.getValueFromSecondClass());
}
```

And the DI will propagate it down to the `FirstClass`!

Comment: Ok but how would you use these in the `SecondClass` as illustrated in my example?

Comment: I believe this is also an "Accepted answer". I like this solution too. But you mentioned that " this is not the best solution". so I don't know what this is lacking. I'd also like you to understand that the example  I used in the OP is just for illustration purpose. Although the practical implementation is almost similar to what I have illustrated in the example.

Comment: *It's not the best solution* - practice to keep the `main` class in the class that has other responsibilities. It's up to you if you want to move that part outside to a separate class which only has main method.
Check out the SOLID. The "S" stands for "Single responsibility principle" which means that class should only do one thing. In the `SecondClass` you have mixed responsibilities where class does its job plus it's used to start the app.